# Getting the last record with Where clause in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql

```
I have a table like this

id    username        sb
1     user1_0001      1
2     user1_0002      1
3     user1_0003      1
4     user2_0001      2 
5     user2_0002      2
6     user2_0003      2
7     user3_0001      3
8     user3_0002      3
9     user3_0003      3
10    user3_0004      3
```

how can i query for example i want to get the last record of sb = 1 the output should be user1_0003?

Comment: In relational database, a row is a single entity. So, the order of the rows does not matter. So, selecting the last row of sb = 1 does not make any logic. If you could mention your purpose of doing this, somebody could help. Btw, if you need to get the record of sb = 1, with the maximum value of id, it will make sense.

Comment: Actually that is what I am asking. I want to get the last record where sb= 1. Which will be output is user1_0003 because thats the last record of sb = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table name is 'table1'. In the inner query it returns the max value of id for sb = 1 and then in outer query we select the record matching returned value.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 WHERE sb = 1);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried it but it output my last record. Its like not reading the WHERE clause

Comment: No it returns the expected result correctly. Check your query again. Refer this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e31/1) for the result in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am working in Codeigniter.

This is my solution thanks to chandimark

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user WHERE sb = '".$sb_id."')");
if ($query->num_rows()== 1)
{
    $row = $query->row();
    echo $row->username;
}
```

Comment: Though your framework is codeignitor, the question can be generalized to `mysql` as you have tagged. So, accepting this answer would mislead the following users.

Comment: simply because I cannot add tag Codeigniter because I am just starting to use Stackoverflow and not allowed to tag Codeginiter

Comment: Your question is based on `mysql`. So, you have tagged it properly. To answer this question someone needs not to have any Codeignitor knowledge. So, you need not to tag it Codeignitor. Actually the question would have been, _Getting the last record with Where clause_